# R: Selecting certain from a JSON file

Tags: json, r, geojson

I've imported a JSON file into R from ( http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json ) and I'm trying to select only counties in Kansas. 
Right now I have all the data into one variable and I'm trying to make subdata of this that is just counties of Kansas. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is `geoJson`, which can be read directly by `library(sf)`, to give you an `sf` object, which is also `data.frame`. Then you can use the usual data.frame subsetting operations

```
library(sf)

sf <- sf::read_sf("http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json")

sf[sf$NAME == "Kansas", ]

# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 5 fields
# geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: -102.0517 ymin: 36.99308 xmax: -94.58993 ymax: 40.00316
# epsg (SRID):    4326
# proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#         GEO_ID STATE   NAME LSAD CENSUSAREA                       geometry
# 30 0400000US20    20 Kansas        81758.72 MULTIPOLYGON(((-99.541116 3...
```

And seeing as you want the individual counties, you need to use the counties data set

```
sf_counties <- sf::read_sf("http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json")
sf_counties[sf_counties$STATE == 20, ]
```

Comment: So it's outlining the whole state of Kansas, but how do I show the different counties in it?

Comment: @ColinAlbert You need the data set that contains the [individual counties](http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json)

Answer (score 1):

To stay with a JSON workflow, can try `jqr`

```
library(jqr)
url <- 'http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json'
download.file(url, (f <- tempfile(fileext = ".json")))
res <- paste0(readLines(f), collapse = " ")
out <- jq(res, '.features[] | select(.properties.NAME == "Kansas")')
```

can map easily like

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addGeoJSON(out) %>% 
  setView(-98, 38, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(rjson)
lst=fromJSON(file =  'http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json')

index = which(sapply(lapply(lst$features,"[[",'properties'),'[[','NAME')=='Kansas')

subdata = lst$features[[index]]
```